# How to execute async calculation and handle other http requests at the same time?

Tags: java, http, asynchronous, completable-future, grizzly

I want to handle several http request simultaneously. What means that I want the thread that get the http request will move the handle of the request to another thread and will be available for getting new requests, until the handler will provide the result.  I will appreciate if someone can show me how to it right. Thanks!

I tried working with CompletableFuture, but apparently I am doing something wrong, since the thread that gets the request is blocked for getting new requests until the handler finished.

As you can see - only after the handler finished (10 seconds of sleep) - the request thread get the new request, so I have no advantage that the handler was executed in another thread.

```
@GET
@Path("/{phoneNumber}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response query() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException 
{   
    log.debug("get a request");                                         
    String message = calculateAsync().get();
    return Response.ok(message).build();
}

public Future<String> calculateAsync() throws InterruptedException 
{
    CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<String>();
    completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                log.debug("finish waiting");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "hello";
        });
    return completableFuture;
}
```

> 2019-06-21 06:38:48,080 DEBUG [grizzly-http-server-0]
>   [com.xconnect.np.test.superquery.suppliers.http.QueryResource] - get a
>   request 2019-06-21 06:38:58,081 DEBUG
>   [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1]
>   [com.xconnect.np.test.superquery.suppliers.http.QueryResource] -
>   finish waiting 2019-06-21 06:38:58,116 DEBUG [grizzly-http-server-0]
>   [com.xconnect.np.test.superquery.suppliers.http.QueryResource] - get a
>   request   2019-06-21 06:39:08,113 DEBUG
>   [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1]
>   [com.xconnect.np.test.superquery.suppliers.http.QueryResource] -
>   finish waiting

Comment: I am not that familier with Java 8, but there must be something called as Callback, using which you should be able to manage your async calculation and returning response. You may also need to check or change your REST API implementation. (not sure though)

Comment: Can you check https://www.callicoder.com/java-8-completablefuture-tutorial/ ? It seems you should be able to handle it using `thenApply` method. and I think `@Suspended AsyncResponse response` is also useful.

Comment: Also in this tutorial: he get method still blocks the main thread:

CompletableFuture<String> whatsYourNameFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
   try {
       TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       throw new IllegalStateException(e);
   }
   return "Rajeev";
});

// Attach a callback to the Future using thenApply()
CompletableFuture<String> greetingFuture = whatsYourNameFuture.thenApply(name -> {
   return "Hello " + name;
});

// Block and get the result of the future.
System.out.println(greetingFuture.get());

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it not using completableFuture (that I am still don't understand how it is useful, if in the end you need to call the `get()` method and be blocked until it ends), but using the `@Suspended AsyncResponse response`, like  agpt suggested.

Here is the code:

```
  @GET
  @Path("/{phoneNumber}")
  @Consumes("application/json")
   public void submit(@PathParam("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber, final @Suspended AsyncResponse response1) {
      log.debug("get a request " +phoneNumber);
      new Thread() {
         public void run() {
            String confirmation = process(phoneNumber);
            Response response = Response.ok(confirmation,
                                            MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE)
                                        .build();
            response1.resume(response);
         }
      }.start();
      log.debug("the submit finish " + phoneNumber);
   }


  public String process(String phoneNumber)
  {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            log.debug("finish waiting "+phoneNumber);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String res = "hello" + phoneNumber;
        return res;
  }
```

> 2019-06-23 09:54:20,157 DEBUG [grizzly-http-server-0]
>   [com.xconnect.np.test.superquery.suppliers.http.QueryResource] - get a
>   request 1 2019-06-23 09:54:20,158 DEBUG [grizzly-http-server-0]
>   [com.xconnect.np.test.superquery.suppliers.http.QueryResource] - the
>   submit finish 1 2019-06-23 09:54:22,026 DEBUG [grizzly-http-server-0]
>   [com.xconnect.np.test.superquery.suppliers.http.QueryResource] - get a
>   request 2 2019-06-23 09:54:22,026 DEBUG [grizzly-http-server-0]
>   [com.xconnect.np.test.superquery.suppliers.http.QueryResource] - the
>   submit finish 2 2019-06-23 09:54:30,158 DEBUG [Thread-2]
>   [com.xconnect.np.test.superquery.suppliers.http.QueryResource] -
>   finish waiting 1 2019-06-23 09:54:32,027 DEBUG [Thread-3]
>   [com.xconnect.np.test.superquery.suppliers.http.QueryResource] -
>   finish waiting 2